# Does Temperature Affect Rate of Reaction of Electrolytic Cell

Tags: redox, electrolysis

I completed an electrolysis experiment. I used copper electrodes and a copper sulphate solution, and my independant variable was the temperature of the electrolyte. I was just wondering if increasing the temperature has a positive correlation?

Comment: What were the results of your experiment?

Comment: The general trend was as the temperature increased, so did the rate of reaction. But only slightly. The experiment was controlled quite badly so this may be due to systematic error.